# DOMXpath - Get href attribute and text value of an a element

Tags: php, xpath, domxpath

So I have a HTML string like this:

```
<td class="name">
   <a href="/blah/somename23123">Some Name</a>
</td>
<td class="name">
   <a href="/blah/somename28787">Some Name2</a>
</td>
```

Using XPath I'm able to get value of href attribute using this Xpath query:

```
 $domXpath = new \DOMXPath($this->domPage);
 $hrefs = $domXpath->query("//td[@class='name']/a/@href");
 foreach($hrefs as $href) {...}
```

And It's even easier to get a text value, like this:

```
 // Xpath auto. strips any html tags so we are 
 // left with clean text value of a element
 $domXpath = new \DOMXPath($this->domPage);
 $names = $domXpath->query("//td[@class='name']/");
 foreach($names as $name) {...}
```

Now I'm curious to know, how can I combine those two queries to get both values with only one query (If it's something like that even posible?).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Fetch

```
//td[@class='name']/a
```

and then pluck the text with `nodeValue` and the attribute with `getAttribute('href')`.

Apart from that, you can combine Xpath queries with the Union Operator `|` so you can use

```
//td[@class='name']/a/@href|//td[@class='name']
```

as well.

Comment: Thank you for solution, and for side note about union operator (It will come in handy).

Answer (score 18):

To reduce the code to a single loop, try:

```
$anchors = $domXpath->query("//td[@class='name']/a");
foreach($anchors as $a)
{ 
    print $a->nodeValue." - ".$a->getAttribute("href")."<br/>";
}
```

As per above :) Too slow ..

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I gave you vote up, but Gordon gets vote up and accepted answer (after all he was the first to post the answer :)).

Answer (score 6):

### Simplest way, `evaluate` is for this task!

The simplest way to obtain a value is by [`evaluate()` method](http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php):

```
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$v = $xp->evaluate("string(/etc[1]/@stringValue)");
```

Note: important to limit XPath returns to 1 item (the first `a` in this case), and *cast* the value with `string()` or `round()`, etc.

---

So, in a set of multiple items, using your `foreach` code,

```
 $names = $domXpath->query("//td[@class='name']/");
 foreach($names as $contextNode) {
    $text = $domXpath->evaluate("string(./a[1])",$contextNode);
    $href = $domXpath->evaluate("string(./a[1]/@href)",$contextNode);
 }
```

PS: this example is only for `evaluate`'s illustration... When the information already exists at the node, use what offers **best performance**, as methods `getAttribute()`, `saveXML()`, etc.  and properties as `$nodeValue`, `$textContent`, etc. [supplied by `DOMNode`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php). 
See @Gordon's answer for this particular problem. 
The *XPath subquery* (at context) is good for complex cases — or symplify your code, avoiding to check *hasChildNodes()* + loop for *$childNodes*, etc. with no significative gain in performance.

Comment: `evaluate` here is not a "dangerous thing" like Javascript's `eval`. It is only an alternate method name  for **"subquery"** (in XPath or DOM context). As it's definition say, *"Evaluates the given XPath expression and returns a typed result if possible"*.