# DOMXPath get first value of query

Tags: php, domxpath

considering you're searching just one specific value is there to get the only and first result directly without parsing the result with foreach?
Like this:

```
$elements = $dom_xpath->query('//span[@id="loginName"]');


echo $elements->firstNode->nodeValue; // this doesn't exist of course
```

the html code is

```
<div>
  <div id="name">text<span id="loginName">Me</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: To get a value, use `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are *sure* there will be a match, you can use

```
echo $dom_xpath->query('//span[@id="loginName"]')->item(0)->nodeValue;
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need to retrieve the plain-text string inside that `<span>` element, namely `"Me"`, you can use `evaluate` instead of `query`:

```
$xp->evaluate('string(//span[@id="loginName"])')
```

This is probably more what you're looking for. It returns:

```
string(2) "Me"
```

Probably this is helpful, otherwise, what [Jon wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10164228/367456).