# How get value using xPath php

Tags: php, xpath

i have an xml like:

```
<AvailableCatgs>
   <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>01</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>1857.48</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
    <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>13</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>1900.40</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
   <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>09</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>22.3</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
</AvailableCatgs>
```

I have to loop all `AviableCatgs` and take value of `CategoryCode` and `Pr`. What i've done is:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($mainXml);
$path = "//AvailableCatg";
$res = $xpath -> query($path);
foreach ($res as $aviable) {
   print_r($aviable->CategoryCode->nodeValue);
}
```

But it doesn't print me nothing...
How can i do? thanks!!

Comment: To get a value, use `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with relative XPath queries, like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadXML( $xml); // Your XML from above

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc);
foreach( $xpath->query( "//AvailableCatg") as $el) {
    $ccode = $xpath->query( 'CategoryCode', $el)->item(0); // Get CategoryCode
    $pr = $xpath->query( 'Pr', $el)->item(0); // Get Pr
    var_dump($ccode->nodeValue . ' ' . $pr->nodeValue);
}
```

This will print:

```
string(10) "01 1857.48" 
string(10) "13 1900.40" 
string(7) "09 22.3"
```

Comment: Sorry :) soap server gives me an xml different from documentation.. so the correct tag is AvailableCategory.. so your code works good!!! thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do this easily with SimpleXml:

```
<?php
$xml=<<<x
<AvailableCatgs>
   <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>01</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>1857.48</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
    <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>13</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>1900.40</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
   <AvailableCatg>
      <CategoryCode>09</CategoryCode>
      <Pr>22.3</Pr>
   </AvailableCatg>
</AvailableCatgs>
x;


$s=  simplexml_load_string($xml);
$res=$s->xpath('//AvailableCatg');
foreach ($res as $aviable) {
echo $aviable->CategoryCode, " -- ", $aviable->Pr, "<br/>";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
(string) current($xml->xpath("//group[@ref='HS_TYP']"))
```