# Extract value of a input hidden DOMXpath php

Tags: php, xpath, input, hidden, nodevalue

I need take the attribute `value` using xpath, I tried several times but always get `null`.

Here is my html code:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Lat" name="myMap" value="22.445575, -18.722164">
```

Code in php:

```
$val= $xpath->query('//input[@type="hidden" and @name="myMap"]/@value' );

$list=array();              

    foreach($val as $v){
       $list[]=$v->nodeValue;
      }

var_dump($list);
$sValue= (string)$val[0];
```

Notes:

- I've tried with other xpath in the same url and it works, but not with hidden input
- I've tried with `$v->item(0);` or `item(0)->nodeValue;` and they always produce the same result

Comment: To get a value, use `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is your code using DOM xpath :

```
$html='<input type="hidden" id="Lat" name="myMap" value="22.445575, -18.722164">';
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$val= $xpath->query('//input[@type="hidden" and @name = "myMap"]/@value' );
$list=array();              
    foreach($val as $v){
       $list[]=$v->nodeValue;
      }
var_dump($list);
```

Answer (score 0):

i find a solution for you using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser :

don't forget download this library :
http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

```
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$html=str_get_html('<input type="hidden" id="Lat" name="myMap" value="22.445575, -18.722164">');
$input_val=$html->find('input[type=hidden],[name=myMap]',0)->getAttribute("value");
echo $input_val;
```

if you want fetch html from url change str_get_html with file_get_html :

```
$html=file_get_html("http://www.example.com/page");
```

Comment: Well thx for help, the problem is str_get_html, is not a string. Is a code in html page, but i cant save it on variable, if i can save it this work 100%. And with file_get_html dont work :s Anyways i go try more times, and i appreciated your help :)

Comment: in this case you can use file_get_html($url) instead of str_get_html