# DOMXPath object value omitted

Tags: php, domdocument, domxpath

I read many stackoverflow question and I'm using this code but I don't know why this is not work.
Here is a code.

```
$url = 'http://m.cricbuzz.com/cricket-schedule';
$source = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
$classname = "list-group";
$events = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");

var_dump($xpath);
```

Can you please check it why this is not working actually I want to get data from `list-group`

Comment: To get a value, use `evaluate`, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/45010743/287948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is correct. It correctly fetches a list of DOM nodes having the specified class attribute value into the `$events` variable:

```
$events = $xpath->query("//*[contains(@class, '$classname')]");
```

which is an instance of `DOMNodeList`. Next you should iterate the list and fetch the data you need *from `$events`*. For example, if you need the outer HTML for the nodes, use something like this:

```
foreach ($events as $e) {
  printf("<<<<<\n%s\n>>>>>\n", $e->ownerDocument->saveXML($e));
}
```

P.S.: I would rename `$events` to `$elements`.

Comment: this code is not working for me i checked it in `var_dump` it give me this `object value omitted`

Comment: Is there any problem in my wamp server

Comment: @AzeemHaider, check out [this](https://eval.in/680762) fiddle. I have replaced `file_get_contents()` with a here document as the server doesn't allow it. Also try `echo` or `printf` instead of `var_dump`. You may have some extension installed that overrides the behavior of `var_dump` (`xdebug`, I guess)